# TortoiseGit won't detect saved credentials during commit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I am trying to do commit to git repo using TortoiseGit. I've set up credentials and pull works just fine. But when I try to do commit to repo I get this message:

[image]

I've added new user to Credentials:

[image]

And I've set up that it should read Local, but it won't save it, when I return to settings, Global is selected:

[image]

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Pull is working, but commit is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with credentials. Git requires commits to be "signed" with a name and an email address.

You need to do:

1. Settings -> Git -> Configure source : select Local
2. un-check the "inherit" checkboxs for Name and Email
3. Type your Name(user name) and Email(user email)
4. Save

"Local" means those setting values are for that repository only.

---

Recommend:

1. Settings -> Git -> Configure source : select **Global**
2. un-check the "inherit" checkboxs for Name and Email
3. Type your Name(user name) and Email(user email)
4. Save

So that no need set Name and Email again and again for every single repository.